# Javascript: Why would img resize when onclick?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, resize

I am trying to learn and I cannot figure out why when I do an onclick the image gets larger or smaller for each picture? I am using the same file image, just blurred it out (in an editor) and resaved each with 'blur' added to the file name. My goal is to create a game where you click the image and then the clear image gets revealed.

```
[Starting game with images blurred] 
https://gyazo.com/e4a4193070b8aff0b6c2c040025d0327
[Click image and resizes to a larger size on the click then the blurred 
 image size]
https://gyazo.com/430e0a5a5664d2be4b84d269e676b67e
[Image resizes to a smaller image, Greedo turns into a smaller image]
 https://gyazo.com/a90a13de27076ebaf04eed85377ac400
```

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Star Wars Image Guess </title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 20px;
        }
        img {
            margin: 20px;
            width:"400px";
            height: "400px";
        }
        .src {
            margin: 20px;
            width:"400px";
            height: "400px";
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = init;
        function init() {
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for (var i  = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].onclick = showAnswer;
        }
    };
        function showAnswer(eventObj) {
            
            var image = eventObj.target;
            var name = image.id;
            name = name + ".jpg";
            image.src = name;

            setTimeout(reblur, 2000, image);
        }
        function reblur(image) {
            var name = image.id;
            name = name + "blur.jpg";
            image.src = name;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="one" src="oneblur.jpg">
    <img id="two" src="twoblur.jpg">
    <img id="three" src="threeblur.jpg">
    <img id="four" src="fourblur.jpg">
    <img id="five" src="fiveblur.jpg">
    <img id="six" src="sixblur.jpg">
    <img id="seven" src="sevenblur.jpg">
    <img id="eight" src="eighteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="nine" src="nineblur.jpg">
    <img id="ten" src="tenblur.jpg">
    <img id="eleven" src="elevenblur.jpg">
    <img id="twelve" src="twelveblur.jpg">
    <img id="thirteen" src="thirteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="fourteen" src="fourteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="fifteen" src="fifteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="sixteen" src="sixteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="seventeen" src="seventeenblur.jpg">
    <img id="eighteen" src="eighteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="nineteen" src="nineteenblur.jpg">
    <img id="twenty" src="twentyblur.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you please insert a code snippet so I can help you?

Comment: Hi! I put the whole code into my post, is it showing in my original post?

Comment: I want to see a code snippet

Comment: Can you explain which snippet of the code you are referring to? I am not sure I understand what it is you are looking for.

Comment: In stackoverflow you are able to add a code snippet so that people can better understand what the output looks like

Comment: Thank you I do see that in there now! The images were all showing up as broken so I will add a screen recording of what I am seeing.

Comment: Alright, thank you, hopefully I can help you out

Comment: stackoverflow said I could not embed images yet. They provided a link but it doesn't work for me, if it works for you awesome, otherwise I may be up a creek without a paddle.

Comment: Maybe you could record your screen and upload it somewhere so I can see it

Comment: I added a few links to screen shots, sometimes the photo gets smaller on click and sometimes larger, but they are the same image, just one is blurred.

Comment: I believe it is because of your different images. I believe the non blurred images and the blurred images might have different resolution sizes.

Comment: What you should do is keep the images blurred with css filter:blur() and when it is clicked, remove that filter to unreveal the image

Comment: That didn't help. I just looked at the files again and the file info windows 10 is telling me is that the dimensions of the blur image versus the unblur image are different - EVEN THOUGH PHOTOS in Windows10 shows them as the same display size when it opens them. Ugh. May not have to do with the code at all it seems

Comment: Thank you for your help Love2Code and Have a happy New Year!

Comment: Could you try to use the css blur filter instead of changing the files?

Comment: ooo thats a good thought

Comment: Yes, so by default you should blur the images through css filters. Then, you should remove the blur when the user clicks and reblur it when you want. Let's see if it works